# Design of user registration form with unique username

Tags: django

I have a general design question about Django. Suppose I want to create a template with a registration form, which lets the user type in their name and press a submit button. I then want to check in the database whether a user already exists with this name. If this name does exist, I want to inform the user, and return back to the template. Otherwise, I want to create this user in the database.

The way I can think to do this is to look in the database and see if a user with this name exists, and if it does, I would add an extra bit of information to the context sent to the template. This extra bit of information would inform my template to display a line saying something like "{{ username }} already exists." If the information does not exist, then the template does not display anything.

Is this a suitable solution? My only issue now then, is how can I determine, in the template, whether a variable in the context does or does not exist?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a job for [Django forms!](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/)
These are used to validate input from the user.